# Excel - Search from range, not specific cell?

Tags: excel, search, substring

I have a range of cells in column I2:I8:

```
WILEY
ELSEVIER
SPRINGER
TAYLOR
SAGE
OXFORD
CAMBRIDGE
```

I want to use the SEARCH function on column G, so that it'll search for any one of the values in this range, and return true/false to column H if it finds anything.
The problem is, that the values in column G are also longer, and the string in column I will only be a substring of the column G text.
Column G contains (for example):

```
BLACKWELL PUBL LTD
ISRAEL MEDICAL ASSOC JOURNAL
PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD
PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD
MOSBY, INC
OXFORD UNIV PRESS
CELL PRESS
AMER COLL PHYSICIANS
NATURE PUBLISHING GROUP
COLD SPRING HARBOR LAB PRESS, PUBLICATIONS DEPT
AMER COLL PHYSICIANS
MASSACHUSETTS MEDICAL SOC
WILEY-BLACKWELL
BLACKWELL PUBLISHING INC
AMER ASSOC ADVANCEMENT SCIENCE
OXFORD UNIV PRESS
MASSACHUSETTS MEDICAL SOC
OXFORD UNIV PRESS
ACADEMIC PRESS INC ELSEVIER SCIENCE
ACADEMIC PRESS LTD- ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD
```

So for examples, each time the word Wiley, Oxford, Elsevier etc appear in column G (such as in OXFORD UNIV PRESS or WILEY-BLACKWELL or ACADEMIC PRESS INC ELSEVIER SCIENCE), it will return true in column H.

I have build the following functions:

```
=(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(($I$2:$I$8),G2)))
=(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(($I$2:$I$2:$I$3:$I$3:$I$4:$I$4:$I$5:$I$5:$I$6:$I$6:$I$7:$I$7:$I$8:$I$8),G23)))
```

But they do not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Example of wanted result:

```
BLACKWELL PUBL LTD                          FALSE   WILEY
ISRAEL MEDICAL ASSOC JOURNAL                FALSE   ELSEVIER
PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD               TRUE    SPRINGER
PERGAMON-ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD               TRUE    TAYLOR
MOSBY, INC                                  FALSE   SAGE
OXFORD UNIV PRESS                           TRUE    OXFORD
CELL PRESS                                  FALSE   CAMBRIDGE
AMER COLL PHYSICIANS                        FALSE   
NATURE PUBLISHING GROUP                     FALSE   
AMER COLL PHYSICIANS                        FALSE   
MASSACHUSETTS MEDICAL SOC                   FALSE   
WILEY-BLACKWELL                             TRUE    
BLACKWELL PUBLISHING INC                    FALSE   
AMER ASSOC ADVANCEMENT SCIENCE              FALSE   
OXFORD UNIV PRESS                           TRUE    
MASSACHUSETTS MEDICAL SOC                   FALSE   
OXFORD UNIV PRESS                           TRUE    
ACADEMIC PRESS INC ELSEVIER SCIENCE         TRUE    
ACADEMIC PRESS LTD- ELSEVIER SCIENCE LTD    TRUE    
NATURE PUBLISHING GROUP                     FALSE   
ELSEVIER SCIENCE BV                         TRUE    
MOSBY-ELSEVIER                              TRUE    
MASSACHUSETTS MEDICAL SOC                   FALSE
```

Comment: Can you use a VBA example or does it need to be formulas?

Comment: I can use VBA, yes. I already use it for other issues.
But I don't know VBA, it was built for me by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your formula in SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($I$1:$I$7,G1)))>0
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you please explain how this works?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT iterates the range and saves the TRUEs as 1 and the FALSEs as 0 and adds them together, Without it it never saves the result of the loop.